# Installing python library with C dependancies

Tags: python, c, installation, package

I'd like to install the [pypoker-eval package](https://github.com/minmax/pypoker-eval). The author provided a nice readme for how to install the package in windows:

pypoker-eval on Windows

1. install python
2. open visual studio project and change directories to include python directories and fix the path to the poker-eval project
3. build the project, there may be an undefined ssize you can typedef as int
4. locate the newly built dll pypokereval.dll then look at the exports and you will find something similar to init_pokereval_2_4
5. rename the dll to _pokereval_2_4.pyd (your version numbers) and move it into the test.py directory
6. edit the .py files so the imported module is _pokereval_2_4 (your version numbers) not a dynamically generated one

To be quite honest though, these instructions really lost me. I've tried doing some research on my own, and I understand that because the library has some C code I need to compile it first. I wasn't able to figure out though what the purpose of changing the directories to include python directories, does this part mean change the working directory? Also is the compiler I use important? I've dabbled some in C but that was with the Code::Blocks IDE.

I think my main problem is I don't really understand what happens when I install a package. Pip has spoiled me and kept this whole process as a block box and now with something like this I feel completely lost. Any recommended reading on installing packages with C dependencies or tips on how I can get this package installed would be much appreciated!

For reference I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Try pokereval-1.38.win32-py2.7.exe at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#uncategorized

Comment: thank you for this site, I didn't know about it before and looks really useful. This is a different package (which I already had installed), pypoker-eval is supposed to be much faster which is why I'd like to get it.